# Is there a word to replace 'Being different from'?

Tags: phrases, synonyms

I want to say:

> Being different from traditional paper-based reading, computer-based reading, in this case, refers to the act of reading with the aid of computer system, which may or may not be designed for the special purpose of text presentation.

If the sentence can be improved in any way, please feel free to give me some recommendations.

Answer (score 5):

You can use *unlike* to replace *being different from*.

Answer (score 0):

'Computer-based reading is the act of reading with the aid of a computer system, which may or may not be designed for text presentation. It is quite different from traditional paper-based reading.'

Answer (score 0):

*In contrast to* or *contrasting*.

With possible improvements:
"*In contrast to* traditional paper-based reading, computer-based reading refers *here* to the act of reading with the aid of a computer system, which may or may not be designed for the special purpose of text presentation."